# How to add/replace a filename's extension in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to add a particular extension to a file(may or may not have extension), I tried this code:

```
import os
thisFile = "/home/username/myfile.txt"
base = os.path.splitext(thisFile)[0]
os.rename(thisFile, base + ".doc")
```

Any other way ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code. You may be able to get help at codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @HenryKeiter i have modified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's no reason for the `base` variable...

```
os.rename(thisFile, os.path.splitext(thisFile)[0] + ".doc")
```

But other than that, it looks fine to me.